# Place the repository not in the same directory as the working copy

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Is there a way to place the repository (`.hg/`) not in the same directory as the working copy?

Like you can in Git by using `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variables.

Background:
I want to use Mercurial to keep track of modifications in important directories on Linux and Solaris servers.
But I want to avoid polluting delicate directories with any "alien" files (like /platform/... or /kernel/drv/ on Solaris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't.  However, you can always have the .hg directory further up.  You could have it as /.hg and have .* in your .hgignore.  Then just add whatever you want at whatever depth you want.

Also checkout [etckeeper](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/etckeeper/) if you're using this for system files where ownership and permissions matter.

Comment: After searching for a while I can confirm. There isn't a feature like $GIT_DIR / $GIT_WORK_TREE. The next best thing for my case is a symbolic link for .hg/.